# MongoDB query hashmap objects

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, mongodb-query

I have the following MondoDB documents in 'match' collection created by Spring's MongoRepository:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "scores" : {
      "11111" : 2,
      "22222" : 0
    },
    "playerOne" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("11111")
    },
    "playerTwo" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("22222")
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("456"),
    "scores" : {
      "11111" : 3,
      "33333" : 1
    },
    "playerOne" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("11111")
    },
    "playerTwo" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("33333")
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("789"),
    "scores" : {
      "44444" : 4,
      "11111" : 2
    },
    "playerOne" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("44444")
    },
    "playerTwo" : {
      "$ref" : "player",
      "$id" : ObjectId("11111")
    }
  }
]
```

The documents contain matches results between two players. In **score** property are stored player's scores where the *key* is player id and the *value* is player score.

I'd like to get all matches by player's **id** (e.g *id: 11111*) where this player is **winner**, so his score is greater than opponent.

Do you have any ideas how write a query for this? I want to avoid  document redesign, but if it's the only way to write a proper query, go ahead.